# Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Код метода отрабатывает нормально, но еще и выводит "Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed". На stackoverflow есть такее вопросы и они уже решенные. Но я что-то не так делаю, и оно не работает :)
Код должен брать количество одного продукта из бд и увеличивать его на то количество, которое напишет пользователь. Как избавиться от "Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed"

Вообщем и целом, вот код:

```
if (searchedCategory) {
                Statement statementUpdate = connection.createStatement();
                sql = "select * from snacks where category='" + categoryFromUser + "'";
                ResultSet rsUpdate = statementUpdate.executeQuery(sql);

                // add an additional amount
                while (rsUpdate.next()) {
                    int amountFromTable = rsUpdate.getInt("amount");
                    double priceFromTable = rsUpdate.getDouble("price");
                    String formattedPrice = String.format("%.2f", priceFromTable).replace(",", ".");
                    int amountRes = amountFromTable + amountFromUser;

                    sql = "update snacks " +
                            "set amount=" + amountRes + " where category='" + categoryFromUser + "'";
                    statementUpdate.executeUpdate(sql);

                    System.out.println(categoryFromUser + " " + formattedPrice + " " + amountRes);
                }
                
                rsUpdate.close();
                statementUpdate.close();
            } else {
                System.out.println("There is no such category in the list :( \n" +
                        "First, add your \"" + categoryFromUser + "\" using the addCategory command");
            }
```

Как избавиться от "Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed"?

Comment: Где у вас в коде такая ошибка?

Comment: На сколько я понимаю, то ошибка в while. Я что-то рано закрываю. Но где и что я закрываю?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот этот код надо убрать или перенести за цикл

```
sql = "update snacks " +
                            "set amount=" + amountRes + " where category='" + categoryFromUser + "'";
                    statementUpdate.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Нельзя использовать один и тот же statement для разных запросов одновременно. Сначала надо закрыть текущий, а потом только возможно переиспользовать его.

Можно создать новый statement, но лучше обновлять таблицу после ее чтения.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!)

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всего делать прямое изменение в БД, не вычитывая данные.

```
if (searchedCategory) {
  String sql = "UPDATE snacks SET amount = amount + ? WHERE category = ?";
  try (PreparedStatement updateStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {

    updateStatement.setInt(1, amountFromUser);
    updateStatement.setString(2, categoryFromUser);
    updateStatement.executeUpdate();
  }
}
```

Лучше использовать `PreparedStatement` (как в коде выше) и не строить запрос вручную из кусочков текста, так как это [опасно](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0).

А ошибка возникает, скорее всего, на второй итерации цикла на шаге `rsUpdate.next()`, т.к выполнение `executeUpdate` закрывает существующий ResultSet.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!)

Comment: Такие баги, чесно говоря трудно отлавливать, может ещё в триггер посоветуете перенести код?

Comment: Я не понял возражения, поясните. Это абсолютно нормально и со всех сторон лучше делать один запрос в БД, чтобы изменить значение. В этом случае одним запросом гораздо лучше, чем читать в джаву, только лишь для того, чтоб потом сразу записать. Начиная с производительности, заканчивая тем, что операция `прочитать-изменить-записать` неатомарна, т.е. если кто-то параллельно будет менять `amount` для той же категории, то мы просто потеряем такое изменение. Вот это будет реально трудно отловить.

Comment: На то, существуют транзакции, такие операции лучше делать в одной транзакции. Один запрос конечно делать лучше, если это  возможно, но вы нарушили логику. Перед обновлением, делается чтение, и не исключено, что обновление надо делать для *каждого* пользователя.

Comment: Можно использовать транзакции, но придется усложнить код, так как простое заворачивание в транзакцию проблему атомарности не решит. Опять же ударит по производительности. О каком нарушении логики вы говорите? А что касается массового обновления, то один update может обновить хоть миллион записей. С точки зрения производительности такое update будет еще лучше чем цикл "прочитать-изменить-сохранить" для многих записей.

Comment: Что значит не атомарна, и причем здесь вообще атомарные операции? Что вы хотите тут синхронизировать, может быть connection? Логика в том, что вы не можете обновлять все записи одним запросом. Производительность здесь ни причем. Что лучше или хуже, здесь вопрос не стоит.